# JWT, how to write about the user's Permission in Django without session?

Tags: python, django, angular, jwt

It had a permission below when my server was cookie-based authentication.

```
class IsAuthenticatedAndStudentOwner(BasePermission):
    message = 'You must be a student.'
    def has_permission(self, request, view):

        return request.user.is_authenticated() and smart_str(request.user.identity) == 'student'

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

        return obj.student.user == request.user
```

Then, when i use JWT, that `request.user` returns `AnonymousUser`.

```
# login(request, user_obj)
payload = jwt_payload_handler(user_obj)
token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
data['token'] = token
return data
```

So, how can i write this `permission` without session?

Comment: You cannot, the permission requires a logged in user.

Comment: Is there any other methods?

Comment: @panda0 yes — login and authenticate the User.